# How to calculate column in react - handsontable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

Code for this:

```
settings: {
          colHeaders:['Commodity', 'Packaging', 'Quantity', 'Unit Dimension', 'Unit Dimension Length', 'Unit Dimension Width', 'Unit Dimension Height', 'Volume'],
          data: [{commodityName:"", packageName:"", quantity: "", dimensionUOM: "", length: "", width: "", height: "", volume: ""}],

         columns: [

              { data:"commodityName"},
              { data:"packageName", type:'dropdown', source:["Pallet", "Box"] },
              { data:"quantity"},
              { data:"dimensionUOM", type:'dropdown', source:["millimeters", "centimeters"]},
              { data:"length"},
              { data:"width"},
              { data:"height"},
              { data:"volume"},

          ],
          minSpareRows: 0,
          contextMenu: true,
          rowHeaders:true, 
          manualColumnResize: true,
          columnSorting: true, 
          manualRowResize: true, 
          manualRowMove: true,   
          manualColumnMove: true,
          colWidths: [110, 100, 100,120, 100, 100,100,100],

        }


<div id="hot-app">
   <HotTable root="hot" ref="hot" settings={this.state.settings}/>
 </div>
```

I am using handsontable component,

I need to calculate the volume(length * breadth * height) and make volume column disable.

I have researched on component but I did not find any solution, I found afterChange event but unable to implement that.

Please, someone provide guidance on this.

Comment: Looks like you'll want to use [customFunction](https://handsontable.com/docs/6.1.1/demo-summary-calculations.html?#custom) and [readOnly](https://handsontable.com/docs/6.1.1/demo-summary-calculations.html#read-only).

Comment: Yes readOnly working, can you let me know how to work with customFunction

Comment: Can some one suggest me in doing this